# Редактирование пути к картинке

Tags: angularjs

Получаю имена файлов:

```
$scope.record = function(id) {
                $http.get('/files/name/'+id)
                    .then(function success(response) {
                        event.files = response.data;
                    }, function error(err) {
                        console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
                    });
            };
```

Отображаю сами картинки:

```
<img ng-repeat="img in event.files" ng-src="// img.filename //" width="300" height="200" alt="// img.filename //"/>
```

В результате получаю:

```
picture5.png
picture6.png
```

Помогите понять, как в контроллере к каждому имени добавить путь `site.ru/picture/open/`:

```
site.ru/picture/open/picture5.png
site.ru/picture/open/pictur6.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
$scope.record = function(id) {
    $http.get('/files/name/'+id)
        .then(function success(response) {
                  response.data.filename = 
                      `site.ru/picture/open/${response.data.filename}`;
                  event.files = response.data;
              },
              function error(err) {
                  console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
              });
};
```